# How do I call up the modern PrintDialog window for a file

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

in the windows 10 photos app, there is a new print dialog. Using task manager, I traced it to the folder C:\Windows\PrintDialog. According to task manager the program running used the command line argument:

```
C:\Windows\PrintDialog\PrintDialog.exe -ServerName:Microsoft.Windows.PrintDialog
```

But this hasn't worked for me and besides, it has no argument for the image I want to print. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

From powershell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\MyImageIWantToPrint.png -Verb Print
```

Comment: Thanks but this is for the old print dialog. I am trying to open the newer one that looks more like this: https://i2.wp.com/www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/enablemodernprintdialog-1.png?fit=600%2C698&quality=100

Comment: This opens notepad.exe, immediately prints to the default printer, and closes.

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII , then something has either changed in windows, or your associations are screwed up (probably this).